# How to configure Kafka's listeners under public network access

Tags: apache-kafka

The local machine only has intranet IP 11.11.11.11:9999, and then makes the following mapping on the switch:

Public IP: 19999 - > 11.11.11.11:9999

External data is written to `Kafka` through the public network IP: 19999, but it is always disconnected. How should my local Kafka `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` be configured respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to the public IP that is specified by the external producers/consumers when they try to connect to Kafka. They need to match to allow the clients to connect to the broker. E.g.:

`listeners: CLIENT://PUBLICIP:19999`

Alternatively set to `CLIENT://0.0.0.0:19999`.